# GDDR5 vs DDR5 - Which is better?

Tags: video

I'm looking at getting a new computer.... which is better for video memory, GDDR5 or DDR5 ?

**update**

that makes sense considering I'm looking at video cards...

http://www.newegg.com/Store/Category.aspx?Category=38&name=Video-Cards-Video-Devices

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no such thing as DDR5. If they are advertising DDR5, they mean GDDR5. All the G bit means is that the memory is specifically designed to be used for graphics.

Comment: Agreed. This doesn't sound kosher to me either.